# Appsync missing resolver

Tags: aws-appsync

I'm using AWS appsync + DynamoDB.

The problem: I created the new field 'rating' in my 'Users' schema:

```
type Users {
    id: ID!
    first: String!
    last: String!
    rating: String #<----The new field
}
```

AppSync created all the resources and I can create new records with Mutations and that works like a charm.

```
mutation createUsers{
   createUsers(input:{
     first:"John"
     last:"Smith"
     rating:"B" #<---Writing new field without problem
   }){
     id
     first
     last
     rating #<---Confirming that is recorded in DynamoDB
   }
 }
```

The problem is that I can't figure out how to write the resolver to make the following query work.

```
query{
  queryUsersByRating(rating: "B"){
    items{
      id
      username
      rating
    }
  }
}
```

The result is this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "queryUsersByRating": null
  }
}
```

The problem is clearly identified [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/troubleshooting-and-common-mistakes.html) under "Missing Resolver", but there's no clear solution.

I tried attaching the following Resolver directly in AppSync interface but is not working:

```
{
    "version" : "2017-02-28",
    "operation" : "Query",
    "query" : {
        "expression": "rating = :rating",
        "expressionValues" : {
            ":rating" : $util.dynamodb.toDynamoDBJson($ctx.args.rating)
        }
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated, THANKS!

Comment: What's the partition key in the Users table?
What's the error you're getting with AppSync once you attach that resolver?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to write your own resolver for querying by rating, Appsync wrapped all the fields inside `filter`.

```
query{
  queryUsersByRating(filter: {rating: "B"}){
    items{
      id
      username
      rating
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: So yes, basically this is the answer that solved the problem because it states that I need to write the whole Query including the filter part.  I was trying to use the automatically generated Queries located inside the Query folder, but it seems that is not possible.

Comment: I had have a project with Amplify and Appsync, I am regretting for choosing the tech stack. It is great for simple tasks, but when you have complex requirements, the amount of time you need to spend on coding and supporting the system is way higher than traditional development.